# Auto update UI when app is opened

Tags: swift

I have successfully been able to get my weather app working; displaying the current test data and so forth. But the only issue now is I can only get the app to fetch the data by pressing my "Refresh" button I made. **How can I make my app update the UI when it is opened?**

Here is my working code:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit




class ViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var tempLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var humidLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var refresh: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var negitiveSymbol: UILabel!


func getTemp(){
    var urlString = "http://torsher.ca/Weather/temperature.txt"
    var url = NSURL(string: urlString)
    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: url!, cachePolicy: NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData, timeoutInterval: 15.0)){(data, response, error) in
        var urlContent = (NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))
        var tempContent:String = urlContent as String
        println(tempContent)

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            self.tempLabel.text = (tempContent)

        }
    }

    task.resume()
}

func getHumid(){
    var urlString = "http://torsher.ca/Weather/humidity.txt"
    var url = NSURL(string: urlString)
    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: url!, cachePolicy: NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData, timeoutInterval: 15.0)){(data, response, error) in
        var urlContent = (NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))
        var humidContent:String = urlContent as String
        println(humidContent)

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            self.humidLabel.text = (humidContent)
        }
    }

    task.resume()
}


@IBAction func refreshPressed(sender: AnyObject, forEvent event: UIEvent) {
    getTemp()

}
@IBAction func refreshPress(sender: AnyObject, forEvent event: UIEvent) {
     getHumid()
}



        override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

}
    }
```

What I was looking at says to use the AppDelegate.swift file and its built in func "func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication)" but everything I try either breaks the app or just does not work. I want to have the app run the getTemp function, getHumid function and then update the UI with the values like I did in the IBAction functions from the buttons.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:**

```
  //
 //  ViewController.swift
 //  WeatherStation
 //
 //  Created by on 2015-04-16.
 //  Copyright (c) 2015 . All rights reserved.
 //

 import Foundation
 import UIKit




 class ViewController: UIViewController {
 @IBOutlet weak var tempLabel: UILabel!
 @IBOutlet weak var humidLabel: UILabel!
 @IBOutlet weak var refresh: UIButton!
 @IBOutlet weak var negitiveSymbol: UILabel!
 @IBOutlet weak var dateUpdate: UILabel!


func getTemp() //Gets the temeprature from the server and displays it.
{
    var urlString = "http://torsher.ca/Weather/temperature.txt"
    var url = NSURL(string: urlString)
    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: url!, cachePolicy: NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData, timeoutInterval: 15.0)){(data, response, error) in
        var urlContent = (NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))
        var tempContent:String = urlContent as String
        println(tempContent)

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            self.tempLabel.text = (tempContent)

        }
    }

    task.resume()
}

func getHumid() //Gets the humidity from the server and displays it.
{
    var urlString = "http://torsher.ca/Weather/humidity.txt"
    var url = NSURL(string: urlString)
    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: url!, cachePolicy: NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData, timeoutInterval: 15.0)){(data, response, error) in
        var urlContent = (NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))
        var humidContent:String = urlContent as String
        println(humidContent)

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            self.humidLabel.text = (humidContent)
        }
    }

    task.resume() 
}


@IBAction func refreshPressed(sender: AnyObject, forEvent event: UIEvent) //Updates UI with current temperature when refresh is pressed.
{
    getTemp()
}

@IBAction func refreshPress(sender: AnyObject, forEvent event: UIEvent) //Updates UI with current humidity when refresh is pressed.
{
     getHumid()
}

func appWasOpened(notification: NSNotification!)
{
    getHumid()
    getTemp()
}

deinit {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(foregroundNotification)
}


override func viewDidLoad()
{
super.viewDidLoad()
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector:        
"appWasOpened:", name: UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification, object:         
nil)
    }
}
```

Attempted adding the second solution, was not able to run with deinit().

Answer (score 3):

The standard trick to get an app to do something every time it's opened is to store a date in NSUserDefaults the first time the app is opened and then to check the stored date against the current date when the app is opened again. If enough time has passed, you do the deed, otherwise you don't. If you do the deed, then you store the current date back into NSUserDefaults to start a new period.

Answer (score 3):

1st solution: You can use notifications for that, in your `viewcontroller` add this to `viewDidLoad`:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserverForName(UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification, object: nil, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) 
{ [unowned self] notification in

    getHumid()
    getTemp()

}
```

2nd solution: alternatively in `viewDidLoad`:

```
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "appWasOpened:", name: UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification, object: nil)
```

and a new function to the `viewController`

```
func appWasOpened(notification: NSNotification!) 
{
    getHumid()
    getTemp()
}
```

**in both cases** you will need to override `denit` (this prevents the observations to be called when the viewcontroller is deallocated.

```
deinit {
   NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
}
```

Comment: Neither of these solutions seem to work. I am not sure why, they compile but the app does not pull the data nor does it display it. Any other ideas?

Comment: they do work for sure.. there must be something else going wrong. you should try putting a `println('some log informtaion')` to either the block in the first solution or the `appWasOpened` function in the second solution to check if they are called. 

additionally you cann place a call to `self.appWasOpened(nil)` to your `viewWillAppear` method.

Comment: Where do I override deinit? I tried in AppDelegate and viewController

Comment: @MimoBot in the viewcontroller :)

Comment: @MimoBot please update your question with your latest code so we can figure out what is still wrong :)

Comment: Just updated it. That is the code from my viewController as I did not change AppDelegate.swift

Comment: i just tested my code. it works fine. you cannot simply copy/paste you have to adapt it to your own program. for example you need to .removeObserver(self) in deinit and nod 'foregroundnotification'.

put a log in your getHumid getTemp functsion and you will see that they are being called.